# mysql update statement is not executed with variables set within a while loop

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, while-loop

I have a settings table and need to retroactively update settings but the update statement is not executed.

The settings look like this

```
Module.Component.Name.X.Regex.SearchOptions.Replacements.Pattern
```

X = is a number, there could be 1 or 20, this can be configured.

Now I need to retroactively update those settings to this structure

```
Module.Component.Name.X.Regex.SearchOptions.Replacements.Y.Pattern
```

Since there could be more than one Regex-Pattern for search options

I have a working code, but i can only update 1 module and I need to update all.

Following Stored Procedure works fine:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `TEST`()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE oldSettingNameReplacement VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE newSettingNameReplacement VARCHAR(1024);

    SET @oldSettingNameReplacement = CONCAT('Module.Components.Name.1.SearchOptions.Replacements.Replacement');
    SET @newSettingNameReplacement = CONCAT('Module.Components.Name.1.SearchOptions.Replacements.1.Replacement');

    UPDATE settings SET settings.settingname=@newSettingNameReplacement WHERE settings.settingname like @oldSettingNameReplacement;
END //
```

Now this one does not, and I can't figure out why:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `TEST`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE oldSettingNameReplacement VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE newSettingNameReplacement VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

    SET @i = 1;
    WHILE @i <= 2 DO   
        SET @oldSettingNameReplacement = CONCAT('Module.Components.Name.', @i, '.SearchOptions.Replacements.Replacement');
        SET @newSettingNameReplacement = CONCAT('Module.Components.Name.', @i, '.SearchOptions.Replacements.1.Replacement');

        UPDATE settings SET settings.settingname=@newSettingNameReplacement WHERE settings.settingname like @oldSettingNameReplacement;
        SET @i = @i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END //
```

for some reason, the update statement is not executed, I used a trigger to find out if the update is executed, it does not trigger.

I also tried to add "quotes", but this has also no effect:

```
SET @oldSettingNameReplacement = QUOTE(CONCAT('Module.Components.Name.', @i, '.SearchOptions.Replacements.Replacement'));
SET @newSettingNameReplacement = QUOTE(CONCAT('Module.Components.Name.', @i, '.SearchOptions.Replacements.1.Replacement'));
```

Comment: When you use `LIKE` without `%`,why do not use `=` directly?

Comment: you are right, I changed it, but sadly still no effect on the update statement, its not executed.